# Setting and Clearing the Carry Flag with Addition and Subtraction

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, carryflag, eflags

I was having difficulty clearing the carry flag but I have come up with a way to clear it using subtraction but I was wondering if there was a better way someone could share with me on how to set and clear the carry flag using addition and subtraction.

```
.data

    binNum1 BYTE 11111111b

    binNum2 BYTE 00000001b

.code

    main PROC

    mov al, binNum1     ; AL = 0FFh

    add al, binNum2     ; AL = 00h CF = 1

    sub al, binNum2     ; AL = FFh CF = 1

    sub al, binNum2     ; AL = FEh  CF = 0
```

This is what I have to set and clear the carry flag. When I first subtract binNum2 from AL I get my original value of FFh back but the Carry Flag is still set until I subtract binNum2 from AL again. It then sets AL to FEh and clears the Carry Flag.

Does anyone have a better way of clearing the carry flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to clear the carry flag is to use the `CLC` instruction; and the best way to set the carry flag is to use the `STC` instruction.

If you must do it with addition or subtraction for some bizarre reason; the least worst method (for code size) is likely `sub eax,eax` to clear the carry flag, and `xor eax,eax; sub eax,1` to set the carry flag.

*Note: to set the carry flag, `stc; sbb eax,eax` would be even less bad, but that solution probably makes the pointlessness too obvious.*

Comment: But the thing is I have to do it using addition and subtraction :/

Comment: Erm, Ok. I added methods that use subtraction.